# Merging two images to single image then top image become larger in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, xcode6, uigraphicscontext

I have two imageViews containing two different images. My `firstImageview` has main image then I added one more imageview as subView of `firstImageview` like `[firstImageview addSubView:secondImageview]`. I need this to be in a single image.

I am using following code (it works smoothly):

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
       // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
    }
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2),
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2),
                                         roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

But in my resultedImage, topImage `secondImageview.image` becomes larger.

My view looks like (Before merging):

[image: image prior to merge]

My resulted image after merging (top image becomes larger):

[image: image after merge]

How can I merge these images without the `secondImageview` becoming larger?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by following code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImageview.bounds.size, mainImageview.opaque, 0.0);
[self.mainImageview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```